# Addition of two variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I want to add two variance. Example: $\sigma_1^2=10$ and $\sigma_2^2=30.$ Will $\sigma_{total}^2 = \sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2 =40?$

Can I add the two variance directly or is there some law to add two variances.

Please help

Comment: Firstly, variances cannot be negative, you've got something wrong there. Secondly do you know if the random variables involved are independent or not? $\mathrm{Var}[X_1 + X_2] = \mathrm{Var}[X_1] + \mathrm{Var}[V_2]$ if they're independent, or uncorrelated, but without that information you cannot just add them and get a meaningful result.

Comment: thank you for your reply. If they are independent, then i can directly add the variance.

Comment: Yes, add as @stochasticboy says, provided the random variables are independent. // BTW, in your Question it seems you had some negative variances. There's no such thing. So I changed the question a bit, when I put it into MathJaX notation for readability. If you think I did damage, please change it again, and explain what you mean.

Comment: No problem sir...now i just have to make sure that my random variables are independent. With the total variance, I am going to generate random variables using normal distribution (mean=0,total_variance)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick demo that independence is crucial. Let $X$ be a random
variable and let $Y$ be exactly the same random variable: $X \equiv Y.$
(Not just a random variable with the same distribution.) Certainly, then
$X$ and $Y$ are associated, not independent. Let $V(X) = V(Y) = \sigma^2.$

*If* we could ignore independence, then we would have equality throughout
in the following relationship, and thus be able to prove that $2 = 4.$

$$ 2\sigma^2 = V(X) + V(Y) \ne V(X + Y) = V(2X) = 4V(X) = 4\sigma^2.$$

---

*Note:*  Here are some important formulas about expectations and variances
of random variables. You should find these (or similar) formulas in your
book and look at any examples given there.

$E(a + bX + cY) = a + bE(X) + cE(Y),$ regardless of independence.
In particular, setting $c=0,$ we have $E(a + bX) = a + bE(X),$

$V(a + bX + cY) = b^2V(X) + c^2V(Y),$ only if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.
In particular, $V(a + bX) = b^2V(X).$ [Above I used this with $a = 0,\, b=2.$]

Also, setting $a=0,\, b=1,\, c = -1,$ we have $V(X - Y) = V(X) + V(Y),$ only if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.